# Listing Github organization user last access date

Tags: github, github-api

Was trying to list out the users which is **not active for 30 days**, so wanted to do a housekeeping for organization github users. Is there any way of listing out with this criteria? I do found out Github users API and there is one response field called `updated_at`, but this field will only updated when github profile is being update and this API only query on one particular user.

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/reference/users#list-users

Currently using github **Enterprise Cloud** version, and by default whoever user is not active for 90 days it will be suspended, also wondering is there a way to finding the remaining days/time to suspend user?

Answer (score 0):

A graphQL [Repository](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#repository) has `RepositoryInfo` with an `updatedAt`  field.

That means a GraphQL search (which has the [same sort option than GitHub website](https://github.community/t/graphql-sorting-search-results/14088/2?u=vonc), meaning is sorted by `updatedAt` by default) would list all repositories from an organization.

You would then need to [iterate through the results](https://gist.github.com/marjamis/2b0088ead7fcb6ea2ccfb196818b2be6) in order to detects the one updated with a date matching your criteria.

```yaml
{
  "queryString": "org:google"
}

query myOrgRepos($queryString: String!) {
  search(query: $queryString, type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
          updatedAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```